# Sending Form Action as entire url without breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, url

I want this entire string http://mywebsite.com?u=http://othersite.com?thisis sent at once . if I put it in a URL shortener like bit.ly it works, but not if I leave it as it is it breaks.

```
<script>
  function go(){
    window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML='<form target="_parent" action="http://mywebsite.com?u=http://othersite.com?thisis"></form>';
    window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit()
  }    
</script>
```

Comment: That's not a valid URL. Anything after the first ? should be [URI-encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<script>
  function go(){
    window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML='<form target="_parent" action="http://mywebsite.com?u=' + encodeURIComponent('http://othersite.com?thisis') + '"></form>';
    window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit()
  }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape the nested URL with [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in order to make the URL valid.

That means doing something like this.

```
function go(){
    var uri = 'http://mywebsite.com?u=' 
        + encodeURIComponent('http://othersite.com?thisis');

    window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML = 
        '<form target="_parent" action="' 
        + uri 
        + '"></form>';
    window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: @RinaLegrande It [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/LbRuZ/). Strange, because the answer you have accepted has the very same code, without using variables for readability (that does not change anything). Could you explain what is not working?